# Do we have $\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq r}(\mathfrak{m}^n+\mathfrak{p}_i)=\mathfrak{m}^n$ in a local ring, where $\mathfrak{p_i}$ are the minimal primes?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

$\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}\newcommand{\fm}{\mathfrak{m}}\newcommand{\fp}{\mathfrak{p}}$
Let $(\cO,\fm)$ be a Noetherian reduced local ring, essentially of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $\fp_1,\ldots,\fp_r$ be the minimal prime ideals. Then is it true that
$$
\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq r}(\fm^n+\fp_i)=\fm^n
$$
for all $n\geq 1$?

Of course we have the inclusion $\bigcap_{1\leq i\leq r}(\fm^n+\fp_i)\supseteq\fm^n$, so we are left to see whether the reverse inclusion holds as well. Here are some considerations: we have a ring map
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi\colon\cO&\to\bigoplus_{1\leq i\leq r}\cO/\fp_i\\
f&\mapsto (f+\fp_1,\ldots,f+\fp_r),
\end{align*}
$$
which is injective as $\bigcap_i\fp_i=0$. Then the question is equivalent to $(\fm^n)^{ec}=\fm^n$, where $\bullet^e$ resp. $\bullet^c$ denotes extension resp. contraction along $\varphi$. Does this hold here?

Note that it holds in baby cases like $\cO=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(xy)$. Indeed, in this case the minimal primes are $\fp_1=(x)$ and $\fp_2=(y)$. Suppose that
$$
f/g\in ((x,y)^n+(x))\cap ((x,y)^n+(y))=(x,y^n)\cap(x^n,y)
$$
for some $f,g\in k[x,y]$ with $g\notin (x,y)$. Then by the above we have in particular
$$
f\in (x,y^n)\cap(x^n,y)
$$
inside $k[x,y]$. In particular, $f(x,0)\in(x^n)$ and $f(0,y)\in (y^n)$. Therefore, we obtain that $f+(xy)\in (x,y)^n/(xy)$ inside $k[x,y]/(xy)$. After localizing, this implies $f/g\in\fm^n$ inside $\cO$, so we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counerexample: let $\mathcal{O}=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/((x-y^2)(x-y^3)).$ The minimal primes are $(x-y^2)$ and $(x-y^3)$. For $n=2,$ $x$ is contained in $\mathfrak{m}^2+(x-y^2)$ and in $\mathfrak{m}^2+(x-y^3)$ but not in $\mathfrak{m}^2$. For, $$\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}^2=[k[x,y]/((x,y)^2+(x-y^2)(x-y^3))]_{(x,y)}=k[x,y]/(x,y)^2$$

and $x\neq 0$ in the right-hand-side ring.